# Rails: any way to preload (include) parent association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, include, scope, preload

I have a Rails 2.3 app with the following models.

```
class Message << AR::Base
  has_many :message_copies
end


class MessageCopy << AR::Base
  belongs_to :message
end
```

Whenever I query MessageCopy, I always need to reference parent message's attributes. So I always end up pre-loading (via :include => :message) to reduce # of db queries.

So far I came up with this:

```
named_scope :with_parent_msg, :include => :message
```

This allows me easily to do this:

```
@user.message_copies.with_parent_msg
```

Is there a better way to do this? So I don't have to always call with_parent_msg?

Open to any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a [default_scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-default_scope) for this

```
class MessageCopy << AR::Base
  belongs_to :message
  default_scope include(:message)
end
```

Comment: I'm assuming the syntax changed at some point, but this the correct syntax for Rails 5.x:   **default_scope { includes(:message) }**